# Enable/Disable Group Buttons at the same time in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to disable multiple buttons of the same "type" in JavaFX. For example, I have multiple cancel button for different operations, but I'd like to enable / disable them all at the same time, but it seems I can't access them inside a LinkedList.

In the below "minimal and reproducible" example, when pressing start, it should enable the (disabled by default in fxml) cancel buttons, but it does not.

**DemoController.java**

```
public class DemoController {
    @FXML
    Button startBtn;
    @FXML
    Button cancelBtn1; // disabled by default
    @FXML
    Button cancelBtn2; // disabled by default
    @FXML
    Tab tab1;

    public SDK sdk;

    List<Node> cancelBtnGroup = new LinkedList<Node>();

    public void initialize() {
        cancelBtnGroup.add(cancelBtn1);
        cancelBtnGroup.add(cancelBtn2);

        startBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
            tab1.setDisable(true);
            startBtn.setDisable(true);
            System.out.println("Disabling cancel buttons");
            HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();
            test.put("disableCancel", "false");
            sdk.onEvent(test);
        });

        initializeSDK();
    }

    public void initializeSDK() {
        sdk = new SDK() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(HashMap<String, String> e) {
                if(e.containsKey("disableCancel")) {
                    for(Node btn : cancelBtnGroup) {
                        btn.setDisable(Boolean.parseBoolean(e.get("disableCancel")));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It seems that I'm overwriting the buttons somehow, but I don't see how. I feel like I'm not understanding the scope inside some of the functions. I tried to make the code as simplified and readable as possible, so if I'm missing something extremely obvious that may be why. The SDK object does not contain objects with the same name, to be sure that wasn't the issue I've changed the names.

Comment: try `for(Node btn : cancelBtnGroup.getChildren())`. and `setDisable(true)`.

Comment: Okay geniuses, I've changed it all to `setDisable(true)` now, the problem still remains that calling `setDisable(true)` does not do anything.

Comment: It seems if I don't directly access the buttons using `cancelBtn.setDisable(true);` it won't work. Iterating through a LinkedList of buttons doesn't seem to allow me to set them to disabled or not disabled. This is the issue.

Comment: The code you posted does not duplicate your problem.

Comment: You edited your code from the original.  Does the edited code actually work for you? Or, do you still have an issue?  If you still have an issue, the issue is likely in the code you don't show.  If that is the case, you likely need to provide a [mcve] to get any further help (nobody can help you debug code which does not exist).  What you have isn't an mcve, the link provided describes what that is.

Comment: The sweet spot is to have just enough code that we don't need to infer _anything_ in order to try and reproduce the problem. Typically this means enough code that it can be compiled and executed—by us, on our own machines, with minimal to no modifications—but never more code than needed to demonstrate the issue at hand. In order to achieve this [mre] you may need to create it _from scratch_, specifically for Stack Overflow. The link gives some strategies to help reduce the code to the minimal amount needed.

Comment: And to address your constant—sarcastic, I assume—use of the word "geniuses" (including in your edit summary comment), keep in mind that _you're the one that has the problem_ and _you're the one asking for help_. This community is also a group of _volunteers_ who owe you absolutely nothing. It's not too much to ask for questioners to put in the effort when they expect help. That said, your new example is sufficient, at least to [point out the apparent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511260/enable-disable-group-buttons-at-the-same-time-in-javafx#comment103353015_58512448).

Comment: glad that you made it in the end, allowing @Slaw to spot the minor error :) Wondering why you use a map<String, String>? You might have confused yourself less with a <String, Boolean> or <String, Object> (the receiver has to know how to dereference which key anyway, so typecast would be safe enough). Btw, your example still isn't _minimal_ - no reason to have a deeply nested ui with lots of unrelated controls when all you need is a handful of buttons in a parent ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I'm disabling the tab which disables all the buttons in it. I didn't notice it because I only have 2 buttons, one of which gets disabled anyway, but the other should not. So to me it seemed that the button was just not responding.

**Solution**

> Remove `tab1.setDisable(true)`

I was disabling all of my tabs so mid-operation the user could not switch tabs, but I forgot that if you disable the current tab it also disables buttons.

I want to thank @Slaw for the help and putting up with my attitude. (I've had annoying experiences with SO too many times before, so I have a predisposition about answers that post the same annoying [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 1000 times. I know I need a minimal reproducible example, but that's not always easy to do especially when you're working with an external SDK and already extensive code. I was trying to make it minimal and reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

From the code you've posted I'm unable to determine why it's not working. However, here's a minimal example using the disable-the-common-ancestor approach and FXML:

**App.java**

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    var root = FXMLLoader.<Parent>load(getClass().getResource("/App.fxml"));
    var scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

**App.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/13" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.example.Controller" spacing="10" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="300"
      alignment="CENTER">

    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/>
    </padding>

    <ToggleButton fx:id="toggleBtn"/>

    <HBox fx:id="container" alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
        <Button text="Button #1"/>
        <Button text="Button #2"/>
        <Button text="Button #3"/>
        <Button text="Button #4"/>
    </HBox>

</VBox>
```

**Controller.java**

```java
package com.example;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Controller {

  @FXML private ToggleButton toggleBtn;
  @FXML private HBox container;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    toggleBtn.textProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when(toggleBtn.selectedProperty())
          .then("Disable Buttons")
          .otherwise("Enable Buttons")
    );
    container.disableProperty().bind(toggleBtn.selectedProperty().not());
  }
}
```

***Note:** Instead of binding the container's `disable` property in code the above can also be accomplished using:*

```xml
<!-- Everything else omitted for brevity -->
<HBox disable="${!toggleBtn.selected}">
```

Of course, if you use something other than a `ToggleButton` then implementing the binding in FXML may not be feasible.

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully it will help you understand my problem.

Comment: @Thomas I can see the problem, though I don't know if the fix is the solution you're looking for. You currently send an event via a `Map<String, String>`. The event you send has the following mapping: `"disableButton" → "true"`. You then parse the value in the `new SKD() { ... }` class. Given the value of `"true"` I assume you want that event to disable the buttons. However, you negate (`!`) the result of the parse operation which gives you `false`. In other words, you're calling `setDisable(false)`. Removing the `!` results in your buttons being disabled.

Comment: ugh @Slaw I see where the issue is in the code I posted, when you're trying to do something quick, you miss things. The problem is, that's not the problem in my actual code, and I'm having trouble reproducing it. I'm wondering if the issue has to do with my SDK being an extension of [TooTallNate's websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) class. Gonna try adding that in to see if it causes any issues